# Automata defined by group presentations.

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, formal-languages, automata, group-presentation

*I apologise if this question is ill-formed or too broad. It's just for fun. I've thrown in the soft question tag for good measure.*

> Let $G=\langle X\mid R\rangle$ be a group. What can be said in relation to $G$ about the automaton $\mathcal{A}(G)$ whose accepted language over the alphabet $X\cup X^{-1}$ is (the set of relators) $R$?

It's a long time since I've done anything with formal languages and automata, so please forgive me as I just point out one obvious feature as my input.

If $G$ is finitely presented, then $\mathcal{A}(G)$ is a finite state automaton.

Comment: Do you mean $R$ or do you mean the normal subgroup generated by $R$? And if your relations involve inverses you need the alphabet to be $X \cup X^{-1}$ in general. Anyway, somewhat related but not really: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_group

Comment: I've edited the question, @QiaochuYuan. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I think that you really want to talk about the automata accepted by the elements of $\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle\leq F(X)$ (where $\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$ denotes the normal closure of the set $R$). This is because we can change the relators really easily, but this subgroup is somehow more rigid. The elements of this subgroup form a language, often referred to as "the word problem", and of course languages and automata are related.

**Theorem.** ([Muller-Schupp, 1983](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muller%E2%80%93Schupp_theorem))
A finitely generated group $G=\langle X; R\rangle$ has context free word problem (that is, elements of $\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$ form a context free language) if and only if the group $G$ is virtually free.

That is, the automata $\mathcal{A}$ which accepts precisely the set of elements $\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle\leq F(X)$ is a pushdown automata if and only if the group contains a free subgroup of finite index.

This theorem is super-important. It says that we can gain algebraic information about groups by understanding their languages of word problems, and vice-versa. It plays a similar strategic role to [Gromov's theorem on groups of polynomial growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_theorem_on_groups_of_polynomial_growth), which says that we can gain algebraic information about groups by understanding their coarse geometries, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G = \langle X \mid R \rangle$ be a finitely generated group and let $W(G)$ be the set of words of $(X \cup X^{-1})^*$ representing the empty word. 
Here are a few results.

**Theorem** [1]. $W(G)$ is regular if and only if $G$ is finite.

**Theorem** [9, 4]. The following conditions are equivalent:

1. $W(G)$ is context-free,
2. $W(G)$ is deterministic context-free,
3. $G$ is virtually free.

**Theorem** [5, 6]. The following conditions are equivalent:

1. $W(G)$ is one-counter,
2. $W(G)$ is deterministic one-counter,
3. $G$ is virtually cyclic.

**Theorem** [3]. $W(G)$ is recursive if and only if $G$ embeds in a simple subgroup of a finitely presented group.

**Theorem** [7]. $W(G)$ is recursively enumerable if and only if $G$ embeds in a finitely presented group.

More results can be found in the survey article [10],
in R. Thomas' lectures [Formal languages and group theory](http://www.cs.le.ac.uk/events/mgs2013/courses/Rick-MGS-Lectures-2013)
and [Word problems of groups, formal languages and decidability](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~mkambites/events/nbsan/nbsan17_thomas.pdf)
or in Part III of the book [8].

[1] A. V. Anisimov, The group languages, *Kibernetika* **4** (1971) 18–24.

[2] A. V. Anisimov, Certain algorithmic questions for groups and context-free languages, *Kibernetika* **8** (1972) 4–11.

[3] W. W. Boone and G. Higman, An algebraic characterization of groups with soluble word problem, *J. Australian Math. Soc.* **18** (1974) 41–53.

[4] M. J. Dunwoody, The accessibility of finitely presented groups, *Invent. Math.* **81** (1985) 449–457.

[5] T. Herbst, On a subclass of context-free groups, *Theor. Informatics and Applications* **25** (1991) 255–272.

[6] T. Herbst and R. M. Thomas, Group presentations, formal languages and characterizations of one-counter groups, *Theoret. Comput. Sci.* **112** (1993) 187–213.

[7] G. Higman, Subgroups of finitely presented groups, Proc. Roy. Soc. Ser. A 262 (1961), 455–475.

[8] D. F. Holt, S. Rees and C. E. Röver, *Groups, languages and automata*, London Mathematical Society Student Texts **88**, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2017.

[9] D. E. Muller and P. E. Schupp, Groups, the theory of ends and context-free languages, *J. Comput. System Sci.* **26** (1983) 295–310.

[10] I. A. Stewart and R. M. Thomas, Formal Languages and the Word Problem for Groups, Groups St. Andrews 1997 in Bath, II, *London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser.* **261**, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge} (1999) 689-700.